# Hello World Cloud Function with Parse and Xamarin .NET

Tags: c#, xamarin, parse-platform

I'm trying to follow the tutorials available on Parse.com for calling CloudFunctions from the .Net API.

Apparently, this should work:

```
var result = await ParseCloud.CallFunctionAsync<IDictionary<string, object>>("hello", new Dictionary<string, object>());`
```

When calling in Xamarin:

```
button.Click += async (sender, e) => {
    var result = await ParseCloud.CallFunctionAsync<IDictionary<string, object>> ("hello", new Dictionary<string, object>());
};
```

It just locks up my mobile app.  When calling:

```
button.Click += async (sender, e) => {
    var obj = new ParseObject("Note");
    obj ["text"] = "Hello, world!  This is a Xamarin app using Parse!";
    obj ["tags"] = new List<string> {"welcome", "xamarin", "parse"};
    await obj.SaveAsync ();
};
```

It successfully saves an object to Parse.

When calling the 'hello' Cloud Function using curl, it works perfectly and returns 'Hello World'

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong here.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var result = await ParseCloud.CallFunctionAsync<string>("hello", new Dictionary<string, object>());
                Toast.MakeText(this,result.ToString(),ToastLength.Short).Show();
```

It was because the example on their website was wrong!  It should be `CallFunctionAsync<string>`, not `CallFunctionAsync<IDictionary<string, object>>` as the type being returned is a string!

Arrrrhhhh.  Hopefully this helps someone in the future.

**EDIT:**  According to the developers at Parse, this should be fixed now / soon.