# Create SDK/API using Parse.Com

Tags: android, ios, windows-phone-7, parse-platform

I got an assignment to write a SDK/API for a mobile app, which will be developed in all 3 platforms(Android/Windows/iOS) by different persons. Since those mobile app developers are outside companies, my company doesn't want to expose any  Data Base structure related information to them.

So they wanted me to use Parse.com as back-end. I was playing with Parse.Com last whole week. But following things are still unclear to me. Hope there could be someone who could help

- Once I go to create an app on Parse.Com it binds me to a specific
  platform so is there a way I could refer data (classes) on one app to
  the other ?
- Is there any way I could expose only few functions out side (like
  GetProductList(), GetOrders()... ) world irrespective of target OS ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Making an app on Parse.com won't bind you to a specific platform. While in the Parse dashboard, go to **settings -> keys** to find the keys you need to access your Parse server for whatever platform you are coding. Parse objects are JSON encoded.
2. You can add javascript functions to your server via Parse's Cloud Code. These functions can be called via multiple languages. Check out the following links to add javascript functions to your server:

   - https://parse.com/docs/cloud_code_guide
   - https://parse.com/docs/js_guide

Comment: Can we access Parse Classes (Which acts as Tables) and expose all the functionalities using javascript ? 
Like 

Get all the rows from a class 
Add / Update rows

Comment: You can access all classes via javascript cloud code. From my experience, almost anything you can do with Parse's javascript SDK you can do in the cloud. There will always be a solution although sometimes you may generate more API requests by working solely in the cloud.

Comment: Also, even if you write a javascript cloud function to pull a particular class, you will need to be able to pull the data from the cloud function for whatever platform you're working with. So if you're coding an iOS app you will need to use objective-c to call and interpret the cloud function.

Comment: I have tried JS samples on Parse.com. And pushed js content to the cloud. It correctly uploaded. But when I tried to invoke the function, though their sample (C#) I am getting following error.

 "Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2[System.String,System.Object]'."
Any idea why, I have not changed anything there

Comment: The example on Parse.Com is wrong. It has to be var result = await ParseCloud.CallFunctionAsync<string>("hello", new Dictionary<string, object>()); Referance : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25110101/hello-world-cloud-function-with-parse-and-xamarin-net